# How do I auto-hide the taskbar?

Tags: raspbian, taskbar

Is it possible to configure the taskbar to auto-hide after a certain period of time in  Raspbian “wheezy” soft-float?

I was able to do something similar for the cursor by downloading a application called "unclutter". Is there any way to do this for the taskbar?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Right-click on the taskbar and select "Panel Settings". Click on the "Advanced" tab, and check "Minimize panel when not in use".

Comment: Follow up question, how do you programmatically set this setting?

Answer (score 6):

FYI to have it gone all the time.

Edit the file `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

1. comment out the line `@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi` with # symbol
2. reboot and the panel should disapear

Still working on Raspbian Buster

---

Find the original source [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/462458/how-do-i-disable-the-taskbar-menubar-in-lxde-on-raspbian-stretch)

Comment: I believe this makes it disappear forever.

Comment: True, I've updated my answer to follow suit. This is the option I needed to use but realize that won't be true for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `autohide=1` and `heightwhenhidden=0` in `/etc/xdg/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel`

If you want to do this via the shell:

```
sudo sed -i "s/autohide=.*/autohide=1/" /etc/xdg/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel
sudo sed -i "s/heightwhenhidden=.*/heightwhenhidden=0/" /etc/xdg/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel
```